# How to load 1000 push pins in nokia maps in small chunks

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, here-api

I am working on a window phone 8 app. Here  I have to show around 1000 push Pins on a nokia map which I am able to show up. But my problem is that the push pins are taking a lot of time to load on tha map making abad user experience.

So Is there any method where I could load the pins in chunks so that the user experience becomes good.

Answer (score 0):

Just load the push pins asynchronously...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464924.aspx

Answer (score 0):

rendering 1000 graphics on mobile device maybe be too much.  Have you consider using any clustering to summerize close/overlapping features?

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HERE_Maps_API_-_How_to_cluster_map_markers

Comment: Hi bcollins, My exact problem is that although I am able to get all the 1000 pushpins on the map. but it is taking some time which is making a bad user experience. I want some what something feature like 20pins get added initially and the remaining gets added afterwards. so user gets a good experience of the UI.

Comment: The above link is an example in javascript .I need code fro window phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

The basic way to do this is to:
- Add some pins
- wait a small amount of time
- repeat until all pins are loaded

When I did this previously (on WP7) it took some experimentation on how many pins to add and how long to wait to get values that "felt right".

Be aware that you may need to be careful with the threads you perform actions on. i.e. Don't do the waiting on the UI thread but you will need to be on the UI thread to do the adding of items/pins.

Also, be sure to test on actual low spec devices (i.e. Lumia 520) rather than the emulator to get a realistic understanding of the user experience.

As has been mentioned in other answers, having 1000 separate pins on the map is unlikely to be the best way to show information to the user or make best use of resources. There's very little point including pins outside of the visible area and when having lots of pins close together it can be hard to see or interact with specific pins.
By having clustering of pins in close proximity and adjusting which pins are displayed as the user pans and zooms around the map you may also avoid the issue of the time it takes to draw so many pins at once.